# Foreach with a for inside does not iterate over every element

Tags: cakephp, loops, for-loop, foreach, cakephp-2.3

Here is the loop:

```
         foreach($event['Event']['user_id'] as $employee){


     for($date; $date <= $end_date; $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date))
     {
         if(strpos($weekdays, date("N", $date)) !== false){
             $real_date = date("Y-m-d", $date);
             $event['Event']['date'] = $real_date;
             $event['Event']['user_id'] = $employee;
             $this->Event->create();
             $this->Event->save($event);
            debug($event['Event']['user_id']);           
         }
     }

    }
```

content of *$event['Event']['user_id']* is following:

```
array(
(int) 0 => '23',
(int) 1 => '24',
(int) 2 => '27',
(int) 3 => '28')
```

If I try to print every *$employee* before the for loop, I get all four records printed, but the for loop is only applied to the first record.
Any help is much appreciated.

Edit: added the result of *pr($event)*

```
Array([Event] => Array
    (
        [project_id] => 62
        [user_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 23
                [1] => 24
                [2] => 27
                [3] => 28
                [4] => 29
            )

        [hours] => 4
        [minutes] => 0
        [assignment] => 
        [material] => 
        [date] => 2013-10-6
        [start_time] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 09
                [min] => 00
            )

        [finish_time] => Array
            (
                [hour] => 13
                [min] => 00
            )

        [repeat] => 0
        [finish_date] => 
        [weekdays] => 
    )
```

)

Comment: Can u add the array that you are foreaching ($event['Event']['user_id']) ??

Comment: It is included at the end of the question.

Comment: Can you do a `pr($event)` and post that?

Comment: Just added, you can find the results at the end of the question. Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let see, in the first loop of the `for`, you do this

```
 for($date; $date <= $end_date; $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date))
 {
     if(strpos($weekdays, date("N", $date)) !== false){
         $real_date = date("Y-m-d", $date);
         $event['Event']['date'] = $real_date;
         $event['Event']['user_id'] = $employee;
         $this->Event->create();
         $this->Event->save($event);
        debug($event['Event']['user_id']);           
     }
 }
```

the `$employee` array for that particular case is `23` (going by the example you posted). Pay attention to the particular line inside the `if` statement.

```
$event['Event']['user_id'] = $employee;
```

So basically, `$event['Event']['user_id']` is no longer

```
$event['Event']['user_id'] = array(
(int) 0 => '23',
(int) 1 => '24',
(int) 2 => '27',
(int) 3 => '28')
```

but

```
$event['Event']['user_id'] = 23;
```

instead. Therefore, the `foreach` function only applies to the first record and then stops.
I don't recommend changing a `foreach` parameter inside the `foreach` (like in this case), it always (or almost always) leads to confusion.

As I don't know what you are trying to do with this function, I cannot give you more advice, but rethink the logic to fix this. Maybe a simple variable like

```
$users = $event['Event']['user_id'];
foreach ($users as $employee) {
    /* the rest remains the same*/
}
```

would suffice.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That was one of the two logical errors. The other was that once the for loop is over, the second element of for loop is not being executed since the `$date == $end_date`